# The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have a sample web app that I am writing and im confused why i'm getting this

The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

when i'm not updating the 'Id'?

Ok, so this is what I am trying to do.

I have 2 tables Topics and Posts and --

1. User creates a new topic it should add a topic record on the database
2. Get the topic Id and set that Id to the Post's TopicId
3. Get that post's Id and set it as Topic's LastPostId

I'm re updating the post so whenever I need to display the last post made to the topic 
I don't need to do the "sort by date for all the post inside this topic".
There should be a better way to do this..

When I debug i see that 
The topic category Id is being set as the Topic Id 
which i do not have in my update code.

```
//
        // insert new topic to database

        Topic topic = new Topic();

        topic.CategoryId = int.Parse(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
        topic.Title = postModel.Title;

        topicRepo.Add( topic );
        topicRepo.Save();

        //
        // insert post to database
        PostRepository postRepo = new PostRepository();
        Post post = new Post();

        post.TopicId = topic.Id;
        post.Body = postModel.Body;

        string strUserId = UserAccount.FormatUserName( User.Identity.Name );

        post.CreatedByUser = strUserId;
        post.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;

        postRepo.Add( post );
        postRepo.Save();

        // ***********************
        // update topic last post
        // ***********************
        Topic updateTopic = topicRepo.GetTopic( topic.Id );
        updateTopic.LastPostId = post.Id;

        TryUpdateModel( updateTopic );
        if ( ModelState.IsValid ) 
            topicRepo.Save();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where is the exception happening? I'm guessing it's in postRepo.Save() or topicRepo.Save(). We'll probably need to see more code.

Comment: It happens in TryUpdateModel( updateTopic ). I see that EF is setting the Id (14) to 8 (categoryId) which is weird.

Comment: Can you post postModel and Topic classes?

Comment: @Ufuk Hacıoğulları I am using entity framework

Comment: It might help not to set id's but objects. So updateTopic.LastPost = post instead of explicitly setting the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because TryUpdateModel tries to update all posted values. So if you have one or more values that you don't want updated, you have to do this manually.

For instance:

```
TryUpdateModel(updateTopic,  "", null, new string[] { "Id" });
```

I'm guessing that one property named "ID" is also submitted into this action, causing the error.

Comment: But what if the modified ID is the ID property of a property of the model and that I want to modify the referenced property to the one that has the said ID ??? Example :

class A {int ID; B prop;}

class B { int ID; }

I want to save an object A referencing the object B with id = 2 instead of the one with id = 1 ??? I want to change a.b.ID...

Comment: Uhmm I would actually have to look at the code. But from the top of my head I think you can do this: TryUpdateModel(updateTopic,  "", null, new string[] { "B.Id" });

Comment: Though it's been a long time, @billy, your a object should have a property referencing the b class. Change it, not the id property of it.