# The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an asp.net mvc 3.0 app and using EF 4.1 for my data access layer and unit of work pattern.

Here are my models :

```
 public class UpdateUserViewModel
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Role
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

     }


    public partial class User
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

I pass UpdateUserViewModel to a view and then post the form in the view to the following action :

```
public ActionResult UpdateUser(User user)
        {
            var userObj = unitofwork.UserRepository.GetByID(user.Id);

            TryUpdateModel(userObj, "User");

            userObj.Role = unitofwork.RoleRepository.GetByID(user.Role.Id);

            unitofwork.UserRepository.Update(userObj);

            unitofwork.Save();
        }
```

Problem raises when I Update user role in the view (it is a dropdown list) and try to update it. it gives me the following error :

```
The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.
```

But if i dont update the user role, it works fine.

Would you help me please ?

Comment: I think I found the answer! I tried TryUpdateModel with included list of properties and it worked for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5820285/the-property-id-is-part-of-the-objects-key-information-and-cannot-be-modified)

Answer (score 1):

You can call TryUpdateModel with an 'exclude' list of properties - and just exclude the ID property if that's appropriate for your scenario.

e.g.

```
TryUpdateModel(user, null, null, new [] { "Id"} )
```